# Remove text after the second space

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a matrix like this (each row is a string):

```
m <- matrix(c("Agarista revoluta (Spreng.) Hook. f. ex Nied.", 
              "Amaioua intermedia Mart.", 
              "Baccharis reticularia DC."),, 1)
```

I would like to remove the text after the second space and to return:

```
Agarista revoluta
Amaioua intermedia
Baccharis reticularia
```

I tried some combinations with `gsub` but I did not succeed.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `library(stringr); word(x, 1, 2)`

Comment: @Sotos great! I think i need to explore this package..seems quite handy!

Comment: @Sotos awesome!

Comment: Several relevant answers here: [How to get the first 10 words in a string in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080967/how-to-get-the-first-10-words-in-a-string-in-r)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- c("Agarista revoluta (Spreng.) Hook. f. ex Nied.", "Amaioua intermedia Mart.", "Baccharis reticularia DC.")
sub("^(\\S*\\s+\\S+).*", "\\1", x)
## => [1] "Agarista revoluta"     "Amaioua intermedia"    "Baccharis reticularia"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z383ig/1) and an [online R demo](https://ideone.com/dgSDqB).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\\S*\\s+\\S+)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ non-whitespace chars, then 1+ whitespaces, and then 1+ non-whitespaces
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible (up to the end of string).

Note that in case your strings might have leading whitespace, and you do not want to count that whitespace in, you should use

```
sub("^\\s*(\\S+\\s+\\S+).*", "\\1", x)
```

See [another R demo](https://ideone.com/qaWrqm)

Comment: What is the \\1 replacing? On a related question, I want to do the opposite. I want to subset from the second space to the end of the string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1916067 `\1` is the backreference to the capturing group #1 value. Here is i the first whitespace-separated two words. If you want to get text after the second whitespace(s), use `sub("^\\s*\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s*", "", x)`. The first `\\s*` is just to account for leading whitespaces (they are not counted in).

Comment: It worked! Could you kindly explain in words what the code is doing? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Another possible regex could be,

```
sub('^(\\w+\\s+\\w+).*', '\\1', x)
#[1] "Agarista revoluta"     "Amaioua intermedia"    "Baccharis reticularia"
```

Alternatively, `stringr` package has some nice functions for these type of operations. For example,

```
library(stringr)
word(x, 1, 2)
#[1] "Agarista revoluta"     "Amaioua intermedia"    "Baccharis reticularia"
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses no regular expressions or packages:

```
with(read.table(text = m, fill = TRUE), trimws(paste(V1, V2)))
```

giving:

```
[1] "Agarista revoluta"     "Amaioua intermedia"    "Baccharis reticularia"
```

If every input has at least two words then you can omit the `trimws`.

Answer (score 1):

split the string on " " and then extrat the first 2 and paste them together

```
x <- c("Agarista revoluta (Spreng.) Hook. f. ex Nied.", "Amaioua intermedia Mart.", 
       "Baccharis reticularia DC.")
sapply(x, function(y) paste(unlist(strsplit(y, " "))[1:2], collapse = " "))
```